# $\pi_i\circ f$ differentiable $\Rightarrow f$ differentiable?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given two manifolds $N,M$, I want to prove that $f:N\rightarrow M=M_1\times M_2$ is differentiable if, and only if, $\pi_i\circ f$ is differentiable for $i=1,2$, where $\pi_i:M\rightarrow M_i$ is the projection. I have already proved that projections are differentiable, and so if $f$ is differentiable then $\pi_i\circ f$ is also differentiable. But how can I show the converse, *$\pi_i\circ f$ differentiable for $i=1,2$  $\Rightarrow f$ differentiable*? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use charts. If you have $\phi:M_1 \to |$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any charts $\phi_1$ of $M_1$ and any charts $\phi_2$ of $M_2$, we have $\phi_1\times \phi_2$ is a chart of $M_1\times M_2$. So for any chart $\psi$ of $N$ we have, $$(\phi_1\times \phi_2)\circ f\circ\psi^{-1}=\big(\phi_1 \circ\pi_1 f\circ\psi^{-1},\phi_2\circ\pi_2f\circ\psi^{-1}\big)$$ is a map from some  $U\subseteq_{\text{open}}\Bbb R^{\text{dim}(N)}$ to some $V\subseteq_{\text{open}}\Bbb R^{\text{dim}(M_1)+\text{dim}(M_2)}$.

Now we know differentiablity of a map with domains and co-domain are open subsets of euclidean space is equivalent to differentiablity of each component.

Comment: Thank you! +1 Now another quick question, for every $b\in M_2$ fixed, could I say that $i_b:M_1\rightarrow M$ $p\mapsto (p,b)$ is differentiable since $i_b=f\circ (\pi_1\circ f)^{-1}$ and apply chain rule?

Comment: You are right. Do again using charts. Then it will be easy.